# Tree-like visual representation of data. Which program shall I use?

Tags: graph, tree, graphviz, representation, graphical-programming

I have a specific form of data, something like the one described ahead. 
I have 200 people, and their genomes. Now, they interact in the field, and after some time, they can take up someone else's genome, or may die.
Thus, I have data like,

```
At time 400, Guy134 took genome from Guy156 
At time 400, Guy96  took genome from Guy145 
At time 800, Guy145 took genome from Guy178 
... 
...
```

> Thus, what has happened is that Guy134 took genome from 156, and his
>   genome got lost forever, while Guy145 took genome from 178, but his
>   genome isn't lost but is now present in Guy96 who lost his genome.

Now I need to trace genomes Descendance in a graphical (tree like) manner. To get something like the following:

[image]

Now, I'd be obliged if anyone could offer any help as to how can I do such a thing. Any software, packages, codes, anything would help. I presume I'd have to start with scratch, if something already doesn't exist that can do this. What is the best software, or package to do this kind of thing. 
Also, I'd like suggestions as to if there is a different, better way to represent this data.

I'm a biologist who is not expert but sort of familiar with MATLAB, a bit of Python, and a bit of shell scripting.